# A simple example of a function which has Fourier series but it's not piecewise continuouse for student who are not study maths major

Tags: calculus

would you please tell me a simple example of a function which has Fourier series but it's not piecewise continuous for student who are not study math major? I know some examples, but for understanding them one has to know Lebesgue measure or some special math information.

Answer (score 1):

"Consider the characteristic function c of the rationals; it's 1 at every rational, 0 at every irrational. Its FT is the constant function 0. Because c is equal, almost everywhere, to the constant function 0, they have the same FT. "
    -John Hughes (duplicate question addressed three years ago)

Comment: the rationals are a countable infinity. The irrationals are uncountable.

Comment: Perhaps a less trivial and simpler and useful example: at zero function is defined an impulse with area one. At all other places it is undefined. It has a nonzero FT and it is not continuous anywhere.